# Add elements to an array in a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails

I have a file with a table that show a relationship between some users:

```
user1.  user2
a.       1
b.       1
c.       2
d.       2
e.       2

...
```

For this I want to create this kind of hash:

my_hash = {"1"=> ['a','b'], "2"=> ['c', 'd', 'e']}

The problem I'm having right now is I can't find a way to add to the array:

Fo example, I have `my_hash = {"1"=> ['a'], "2"=> ['c', 'd', 'e']}`, how do I add 'b' to the key "1"?

I tried

```
months = Hash.new

months['1'] = ['a']

months['1'] << ['b']
```

But I got this result: `{"111-111"=>["1111-aaaa", ["2222-bbb"]]}`

Comment: Where do you get the info for the values `user1` and/or `user2` hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've set `months['1'] = ['a']`, the value of that key is an array.

You want to push `'b'` into that array.

```rb
irb> months = Hash.new
=> {}
irb> months['1'] = ['a']
=> ["a"]
irb> months['1'] << 'b'
=> ["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `<<` you have to be sure that value is `Array` or it will be error `NoMethodError (undefined method << for nil:NilClass)`. More safe to use `Array.wrap`:

```rb
h = {}
h['1'] = Array.wrap(h['1']).push('A')
h['1'] = Array.wrap(h['1']).push('B')
h['2'] = Array.wrap(h['2']).push('C')  

# h is  {"1"=>["A", "B"], "2"=>["C"]}
```